# How to link two classes in python for eg a student class and a subject class such that a student class contains a number objects of subject class

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop

```
class Subject:
    def __init__(self, name, midTerm, attend, classtest, endterm):
        self.name = name
        self.midTerm = midTerm   
        self.attend = attend    
        self.classtest = classtest   
        self.endterm = endterm 
        self.total = 0
        self.grade = 'F'
        newAttend = attendanceMarks(self.attend)
        if newAttend != -1:
            self.total = newAttend + midTermMarks(midTerm) + classTestMarks(classtest) + endTermMarks(endterm)
            self.grade = gradeCal(self.total)
        else:
            self.grade = 'F'

class Student:
    sub = []
    def __init__(self, name, roll, s1, s2, s3, s4):
        self.name = name
        self.roll = roll
        self.sub.append(s1)
        self.sub.append(s2)
        self.sub.append(s3)
        self.sub.append(s4)
        
        self.tTotal = self.sub[0].total + self.sub[1].total + self.sub[2].total + self.sub[3].total
        self.tGrade = gradeCal(self.tTotal / 4)
        
        
                       
st1 = Student("Akash", 17, Subject("Compiler Design", 50, 76, 50, 100), Subject("Software Engineering", 50, 76, 50, 100), Subject("Machine Learning", 50, 76, 50, 100), Subject("Natural Language Processing", 50, 76, 50, 100))

st2 = Student("Juan", 23, Subject("Compiler Design", 30, 76, 25, 50), Subject("Software Engineering", 25, 76, 34, 60), Subject("Machine Learning", 39, 76, 45, 66), Subject("Natural Language Processing", 32, 76, 44, 77))

st1.tTotal
st2.tTotal
```

Here both st1.tTotal and st2.tTotal gives the same output. Some of the methods used above are already defined and the code executes successfully. The total and grade inside subject class are calculated in terms of 100 marks and grades A-F respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `st1.tTotal` and `st2.tTotal` give the same output is that you're defining `Student.sub` as a class variable so it is shared across all `Student` instances. You should instead make `Student.sub` an instance attribute by defining it in the `__init__` method and bind it to `self` so that each `Student` object has its own `sub` list.

Change:

```
class Student:
    sub = []
    def __init__(self, name, roll, s1, s2, s3, s4):
        self.name = name
        self.roll = roll
        self.sub.append(s1)
        self.sub.append(s2)
        self.sub.append(s3)
        self.sub.append(s4)
```

to:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, roll, s1, s2, s3, s4):
        self.name = name
        self.roll = roll
        self.sub = []
        self.sub.append(s1)
        self.sub.append(s2)
        self.sub.append(s3)
        self.sub.append(s4)
```

or to allow a variable number of subjects for each `Student`, use a variable argument with an asterisk:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, roll, *sub):
        self.name = name
        self.roll = roll
        self.sub = sub
```